# Excel VBA: Conditional Format of Pivot Table based on Column Label

Tags: excel, vba

(Note: This is my first question. Please let me know if I can improve how I ask or explain)

I have created a module that can look through a pivot table on any excel worksheet and apply conditional formatting to each column to create quartile performances.

The pivot table can be any size and have different columns at any point - so I can't explicitly reference a particular column name or caption etc

Additionally, the quartile reporting identifies the top 25% for a particular figure, the next 25, next 25 and bottom 25.
For some figures high is better; for others, low is better.

So I list all the values that are high-to-low in an array, then run a quick "if name in array, rank this way; otherwise, rank this way" function.

All of this works like a dream - until we come to certain fields that result in an ambiguous name issue (and error). It seems that some caption names are similar to the source or database names.

The code reads like this (below).

Any ideas how I can refer dynamically to the column name and identify the column beneath it, please?

```
    Dim myColumnNames As Variant

    myColumnNames = VBA.Array("CONTRACTGROSSVOLUME", _
                            "MigrationVolume")  'etc

'   Set colour choices for quartiles
    Dim myQuartile1 As Long
    Dim myQuartile2 As Long
    Dim myQuartile3 As Long
    Dim myQuartile4 As Long

    myQuartile1 = RGB(146, 208, 80)     'Top Quartile - Green
    myQuartile2 = RGB(255, 255, 0)      '2nd Quartile - yellow
    myQuartile3 = RGB(255, 192, 0)      '3rd Quartile - orange
    myQuartile4 = RGB(255, 0, 0)        'Bottom Quartile - red

    Dim myRankingFactor As Boolean
    myRankingFactor = True   'true is low to high / false is high to low ranking

    Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim myPivotTableName As String

    For Each myPivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        myPivotTableName = myPivotTable.Name
    Next

    Dim myPivotField As PivotField
    Dim myPivotSourceName As String

    Set myPivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(myPivotTableName)


    For Each myPivotField In myPivotTable.DataFields


        'get the source name for the pivot field
        myPivotSourceName = myPivotField.Name

        'Check if column name is in our list to rank high-to-low
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(myPivotSourceName, myColumnNames, False)) Then

            'This column name is in our list of names that should be ranked high-to-low (ie. Higher is better)
            myRankingFactor = True

        Else
            'This column name is not in our list and should be ranked low-to-high (ie. lower is better)
            myRankingFactor = False

        End If
```

The error then comes on the following line:

```
 myPivotTable.PivotSelect (myPivotSourceName), xlDataOnly, True
```

I've tried refering to the column with .caption, .name etc - no avail.
Any dieas on what I need to do to dynamically get the column name, check if it's in the array of names, then refer to that entire column to apply my formatting, please?

Thanks

---

Additional info:

The value is passing (apparently) correctly.
The column name displayed is "My Volume" and the variable is displaying "My Volume" as the value.
It's source name is "MYVOLUME" (one word), which I've also tried referencing without success.

The error generated is:

> Run-time error '1004': An item name is ambiguous. Another field in the
>   pivottable report may have an item with the same name. Use the syntax
>   field [item]. For example, if the item is Oranges and the field is
>   Product, you would use Product[Oranges].

As an addition, I just manually changed one of the column names to a unique, single word ("ABCDEFG") that is not present in the database, object or anywhere in the data output to see if it would be picked up.

Changing that alias/caption value worked fine and didn't error.

Summary:
It's behaving as if the column name is already used elsewhere in the pivot - but it is not.
How do I explicitly refer to the column name/caption/label, but on-the-fly? :)

### FIXED!

I ensured that the pivot table column name was passed as a string:

```
myPivotSourceName = myPivotField.Name
```

Then rather than referencing the data field with the pivot field object, I referenced the DataRange with the string:

```
myPivotTable.PivotFields(myPivotSourceName).DataRange.Select
```

Works perfectly and is completely portable for any pivottable on any sheet with any fields

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Are you sure the parens in the line where you get the error are OK?

Comment: When the error occurs and the debugger comes up, what is the value of the myPivotSourceName variable?

Comment: It works on almost all columns. Some column errors are calculated fields - but not all. Doesn't seem to be a common denominator in what's causing the error

Comment: All. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myPivotTable.PivotFields(myPivotSourceName).DataRange.Select

This references the name of the column as a string. Works on all pivot tables I've tested it on.

Comment: Essentially, this solution is the same that I sent three days before.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the error by having a data item with the same name as the one of the data fields. For example, if you have the following table from which you create a pivot:

```
Product      Price
Cola           123
Fanta          456
Sum of Price   789
```

then by creating a pivot table, you will have these items: Cola, Fanta, 'Sum of Price', and the following field labels: 'Row labels', 'Sum of Price'.
If you try to use 'Sum of Price' in the PivotTable.PivotSelect function, then the error message in the question will appear.

I think the Name parameter in PivotSelect is not clear enough, I did not find the documentation of the naming convention used in it, so I recommend referring to the datafield explicitly:

```
myPivotTable.PivotFields("Sum of Price").DataRange.Select
```

Note: There are many stylistic errors a superfluous parts in your code, e.g. the parentheses in the line that causes the error are not required, the loops just select the last item.

Comment: Thanks, z32a7ul
"I think the Name parameter in PivotSelect is not clear enough" - I agree, but also can't find a means to refer to the [object].[field].
I can't refer to it explicitly as 1. It has the same error, and 2. the code will be used in various pivot tables as a portable module